# Auto-fitting excel tables with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet of around 20 single column tables that I would like to autofit to a variable row (the last row of data for each).

I currently am using the following code below (which does extend the tables when opening the file), but all the tables are being extended to the last row with data in the whole sheet not for their individual columns.

I'm relatively new to VBA and wanted to see if anyone had any pointers? Or if there was a more efficient approach altogether?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("TABLE_NAME1")
With tbl.Range
    tbl.Resize .Resize(.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)
End With

Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("TABLE_NAME2")
With tbl.Range
    tbl.Resize .Resize(.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your tables are side-by-side, `.CurrentRegion` will refer to multiple columns.

You could find the last row in each individual column:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Me.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' or just use sheet's codename

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        Dim col As Long
        col = tbl.Range.Column 

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

        tbl.Resize ws.Range(tbl.Range.Cells(1), ws.Cells(lastRow, col))
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```